# CSS is there a better shorthand version for border?

Tags: html, css, styles, stylesheet

Is there another shorthand version for border, something like this example:

```
        [top,right,bottom,left, style, color] 
border: 1px 1px 0px 1px solid #000;
```

I'm trying to accomplish the effect similar to this:

```
border: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i prefer the second for more control. shorthand code will become messy real quick when specificity and dynamic styles are in play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border) says:

> Unlike the shorthand 'margin' and 'padding' properties, the 'border' property cannot set different values on the four borders. To do so, one or more of the other border properties must be used.

Your way of doing it with two properties is probably the shortest way. Just go with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to have a border on all sides except the bottom, I think your method is the best to use for standard CSS

I don't believe there is a more shorthand method of doing this